# IDA search and replace all occurrences

Tags: ida

i am sure this is simple, but...
I want to replace all occurrences of command

```
push 801h
```

to

```
push 802h
```

how can i do that with Ida6 ?!

Comment: As a side note, modifying the IDA database (IDB) doesn't modify the underlying executable. Do you intend to modify the executable or the IDB?

Comment: I would like to do both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is by replacing all occurrences of the bytes that represent `push 801h` with the bytes that represent `push 802h` in the file, using a hex editor such as [Hex-Workshop](http://www.hexworkshop.com/) or [010 Editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/).